# spend a specifc UTXO

Tags: bitcoind, utxo

Is there any methods to pick a particular UTXO and send it to a particular address in bitcoin regtest mode using bitcoin-cli other than createrawtransaction and sendtoaddress

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fundrawtransaction` and specify a particular input to be used in the transaction. Bitcoin Core will then choose the rest of the inputs to meet your output amount automatically.

You can also use `lockunspent` to prevent specific UTXOs from being selected for coin selection thereby limiting which UTXOs can be used. Then any time that coin selection is used to create a transaction (i.e. in `sendtoaddress`, `sendmany`, `fundrawtransaction`, `walletcreatefundedpsbt`), only outputs that are not locked will be selected.